# PDO: group a property instead of duplicate lines

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

Good morning,

I have a request that return me several information for a reservation and each reservation can be linked to several room.

Is it possible to have an array of room instead of duplicate the line each time they are multiple rooms for a reservation.

What I want:

```
[
    idReservation1 => [
        "client_name" => "kévin titi",
        "checkin" => "2017-08-08",
        "d_checkout" => "2017-08-10",
        "email" => "titi@gmail.com",
        room_id => [1,2,3,9]//here I want an array
    ],
    idReservation2 => [
        "client_name" => "firstname lastname",
        "checkin" => "2017-08-18",
        "d_checkout" => "2017-08-20",
        "email" => "toto@gmail.com",
        "room_id" => [1,12,13,9]//here I want an array
    ]
]
```

if the idReservation is not the key does not matter, the important here is to have an array for room_id
I have looked all PDO fetch modes but they don't seems to match to my problem.

My request:

```
 $prep = $this->pdo->prepare("
            SELECT re.id as resId, re.client_name, re.d_checkin, re.d_checkout, re.mail, ro_re.room_id as room
            FROM Reservation re
            JOIN Room_Reservation ro_re ON ro_re.reservation_id = re.id
            WHERE re.confirmed = false
        ");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are working with *MySql*: the solution using [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function(to group *room* ids for each *reservation*):

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("
            SELECT 
                re.id as resId, re.client_name, re.d_checkin, re.d_checkout, re.mail, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(ro_re.room_id SEPARATOR ',') AS room_ids
            FROM 
                Reservation re
                INNER JOIN Room_Reservation ro_re ON ro_re.reservation_id = re.id
            WHERE re.confirmed = false
            GROUP BY re.id
");

$stmt->execute();

// `room_ids` column will contain a string like "1,2,3,9"
$result = [];
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    $row['room_ids'] = explode(',', $row['room_ids']);  // converting string with room ids into array
    $result[] = $row;
}
```